# Does invoking getResultList() on javax.persistence.Query execute the query twice?

Tags: java, jpa

When I have a javax.persistence.Query that I'm expecting a `List` from I always check to make sure that the `List` has a size greater than 1 before returning any values. 
e.g.

```
Query q = em.createQuery(sql);

if(q.getResultList().size()<1)
        {
            return new ArrayList();
        }
        else
        {
            return q.getResultList();
        }
```

I'm wondering if when I check for the size and when I return the result if the query is being executed twice.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: Agree, deleted my comment.

Comment: What is `q` in your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getResultList()` executes the query, just as the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29) say.

Do this instead:

```
List results = q.getResultList();
if (results.size() == 0) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
} else {
    return results;
}
```

Of course, if this is a `TypedQuery`, you should add the generics part. It is good practice to return an unmodifiable, empty list from queries without result records.

Answer (score 0):

If `q.getResultList();` is the actual query then yes.

Before comparing i would store it in a variable `List storeHere = q.getResultList();`

Then compare that variable rather than the command.

Comment: It was just an example as to store a variable as we do not infact know `q` is.